# File Shredder c# using Microsoft.WinAny.Helper

Tags: winforms

Hi Guys Im Trying To Use The Microsoft.WinAny.Helper Class i got from [Here](https://microsoftwinanyhelper.codeplex.com/)

i get an error when trying to delete a folder using the Quick Delete method

my code is

```
         try
              {
                  System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(textBox1.Text);
                  fi.Delete(OverwriteAlgorithm.Quick);

                  MessageBox.Show("File Sucsessfully Deleted", "Succsess", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
              }
```

it give me an access is denied error at OverwriteAlgorithm.Quick

```
  Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\Test\Documents\Shredder\New folder' is denied.
```

please help me get access permissions if needed also im Using Windows Forms

Comment: That's a folder, not a file.  Yes, trying to treat a folder like a file produces "Access denied".  Type a filename instead or use the DirectoryInfo.Delete() extension method.  Otherwise a good demonstration why libraries should expose extension methods very sparingly.  You would not have made this mistake if it had a DeleteFile and DeleteDirectory method :)

Comment: o thanks will look into that *_*